# Eclipse. Installing STS4 causes Eclipse update error on Wild Web Developer XML Tools

Tags: spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4, wildwebdeveloper

I did a clean install of Eclipse. After installing the Spring Tools Suite 4 I get an error when checking for Eclipse updates. Any suggestions?

- Deleted ~/{.eclipse,.p2,.sts4,eclipse,eclipse-workspace}
- Installed Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK - jdk-17.0.4.1+1 Windows x64
- Installed Eclipse 2022-06 Windows x86_64
- Help > Check for Updates

  - No updates found
- Help > Eclipse Marketplace

  - Installed tab is empty
- Installed "Spring Tools 4 (aka Spring Tool Suite 4) 4.15.3.RELEASE

  - Confirmed default selected features
- Restart
- Help > Check for Updates

  - Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

    - Wild Web Developer XML tools 0.14.0.202206022022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this and I am still a bit puzzled about why this happens, but you can solve this by adding an additional update site to your `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites`:

https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/releases/0.13.6/

Once that update site is around, the `Check for Updates` can complete.